# Xubuntu 17.10 + nemo + dropbox support

Tags: 17.10, dropbox, nemo

I like nemo in Xubuntu but the Dropbox support doesn't seem to be available for aardvark. I like the folder emblems to show sync status.
Any ideas on how to add this level of support to nemo in 17.10?
When I try to add it with a "sudo apt install nemo-dropbox" I get this:

```
$ sudo apt install nemo-dropbox 
[sudo] password for manny: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nemo-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

The *dropbox* package (.deb file) can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/install.

(And if somebody has the problem that there is no *nemo-dropbox* package in Ubuntu 17.10, you can get it from [ppa:noobslab/nemo3](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3))

Apparently though, the green file status emblems are only shown in icon or compact view, not in list view. Also, running 'Open Dropbox Folder' from the tray icon menu will open Nautilus instead of Nemo.